# jQuery UI Accordion loading very slow

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I have a jQuery UI Accordion implemented and as the page loads, you see content of the three headers and tabs for a few seconds, and *then* they turn into the accordion. I'm not sure which part is causing the delay, and hoping you can help.

In my `functions.php`:

```
// Enqueue jQuery accordion
function product_accordion()
{
    if ((is_product()) || (is_archive())){

        wp_enqueue_style('jquery-ui', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/css/jquery-ui.css', 10);
        
        wp_register_script('jquery-core', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . 'https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.2.js', array('jquery'), '1.0', true);
        wp_enqueue_script('jquery-core');
        
        wp_register_script('jquery-ui', 'https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.0/jquery-ui.js', array('jquery'), '1.0', true);
        wp_enqueue_script('jquery-ui');
        
        wp_register_script('accordion-snippet', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/js/accordion-snippet.js', array('jquery'), '1.0', true);
        wp_enqueue_script('accordion-snippet');
        
    }
}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'product_accordion');
```

The `accordion-snippet.js` enqueued above:

```
      jQuery('#accordion').accordion({ 
            collapsible:true, 
            active:false, 
            autoHeight: false, 
            disabled:true,
            heightStyle: "content"
      });

      jQuery('#accordion h3.ui-accordion-header').click(function(){
            jQuery(this).next().slideToggle();
      });
      
      jQuery('.accordion-expand-all').click(function(){
            jQuery('#accordion h3.ui-accordion-header').next().slideDown();
      });
      console.log("accordion-snippet.js loaded");
```

and you can see it [here](http://levelupnowyou.com/1591113365325/product/testing-2-womens-racerback-tank/).

What is causing the delay in the Accordion being loaded? And / or any tips on troubleshooting this would be great too.
Please let me know if I need to provide anything else.Thanks!

Comment: There is no delay in the accordion loading. The delay is due to fetching that data and then generating the content.  Examine your query process and look for slow queries.  This is a general database and jquery question - not specific to WP.

Comment: Thank you @shanebp. But - the content is loaded much faster than the accordion itself, so I’m not sure I see that. The content is already there, waiting on the accordion which then contains  the content.

Comment: Ok, then it is the accordion is slow. You could put a few alerts in the snippet.js to confirm. One right before it starts processing and one after.  If they appear with a delay between them - you know it is something in the snippet